# Hard drive makes a lot of crackling noises when searching through a large folder and buzzes when I am afk

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I have a WD Red Pro 4TB HDD. Bought it about 3 months ago.

When I open a folder with a lot of files it starts crackling, I guess it's caused by the drive reading, but I haven't had any file misreads or corruptions, so I don't know if the drive actually has a critical issue or not. When I ran crystaldisk it also didn't detect any issues with the drive.

Also, whenever I go afk for a few minutes, the drive starts crackling like it's reading files and recently it feels like it started to get louder and started buzzing.

Is there a good explanation for this or should I contact support for a replacement? I'm asking this because this is a NAS drive and I've never had one of these before, so I'm not sure if the noise is something that's usual for this type of drive.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered returning it under warranty?

Comment: @John I'm considering it now. I just wanted to make sure it was a real issue before doing it since I don't know how hard this process will be.

Comment: I have not heard these noises when using a hard drive. It should be near silent.  Check the mounting of the drive to ensure it is properly mounted and not subject to excessive vibration.

Comment: @John As far as I can tell it's not vibrating, but I might just be failing to detect it, got any tips on making sure it's not vibrating?

Comment: If not vibrating then there may be something internal to the drive and should be returned.

Comment: When running a SMART tool it's good idea to include the report or a screenshot to the question. A SMART tool stating 'GOOD' isn't per se the final word.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I added a picture of the scan, I can't read any more info out of it, but maybe you will.

Comment: @bigChungusAmoongus, nothing alarming at first glance.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Crackling when reading aside, do you have any idea what causes it to start making more noise when afk? I haven't found anything on this issue.

Comment: @bigChungusAmoongus Plenty of things can cause disk activity while your PC is idle.  File system indexing is a big one.

Comment: Yes, I agree with squillman, it might as well be the OS that does it's thing. And such drives tend to be noisier than desktop drives. This is a similar WD RED https://vocaroo.com/2oYPwyPISlE

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Yes that noise is very similar to the one mine makes. Does that mean it's not a cause for concern after all?

Comment: It seems to be a common complaint, is all I can say.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Can you make an answer with that audio link? I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not answer this definitively but:

- 'Noise' seems to be a common complaint with regards to these drives, even driving some to actually record and submit the recording and asking for opinions; https://vocaroo.com/2oYPwyPISlE which I found 'Googling' this particular drive model.
- SMART values of the drive seem to be okay. The larger RAW values seem to represent multiple parameters. For example spin up time, seems 3 separate values, 0006-0134-0138 and shouldn't raise concern
- Unexplained drive activity can actually often be explained by the OS performing activities such as indexing, defrag, perhaps even 'refreshing' depending on specific OS and file system.
- Although this does not seem to be an SMR drive, such SMR drives also could initiate background maintenance in idle time. But so can CMR drives, perhaps less frequent though. Modern controllers/firmware may for example 'patrol' the drive and re-write data periodically.
- You could check if there are ways to dampen the vibrations caused by disk activity which may increase perceived noise. There's all sorts of solutions available on the market.

Comment: the recording that you included sounds normal ... the arm that moves the read/write heads is in a way similar to a speaker cone ... it accelerates and decelerates at very high rate

Comment: @jsotola, Yes I agree. A tad loud but normal, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Western Digital Red drives are so-called "NAS drives". They are intended to live in professional or semi-professional multi-drive storage systems that live in rooms where noise levels are not a concern.

The average consumer hard drive has a lot of design effort and build material dedicated to reducing noise. NAS drives have none of this. They are built to be steady and reliable. Noise is not a concern when designing and building these. In many ways, the louder noise on these drives is a direct or indirect result of design decisions and build choices that IMPROVE the quality and longevity of the drive. Softer or cheaper components in consumer drives may make less noise, but they may also wear out more quickly. Heads moving more slowly may make less noise but also result in longer seek times.

So, unless there is an indication other than the noise that this drive is failing, do not consider this abnormal-to-you noise level to be a problem indicator on its own.